# NSDate month and week day localized

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to display a localized date (with the week day and month in letters) depends on the language of the phone (not the region format).

I tried :

```
// Date formatter
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSLog(@"locale : %@", locale.localeIdentifier);
[df setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE dd MMMM" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
```

But when I change the language of the phone, it changes nothing, it still displays in french. How can I make it work ?

Comment: try restarting your app after you change device settings

Comment: I want that the week day and the month are displayed in the language of the phone. So, if I change the language from "Francais" to "English", I want to see "Friday 13 september".

Comment: Yes but I want that the day and the month change depends on the phone language. How can I do this ?

Comment: Note that the above code is not setting the locale of the DateFormatter, but merely using the locale to condition the `dateFormatFromTemplate` call.  Nothing about the language is conveyed to the DateFormatter in that operation (though of course the DateFormatter is, by default, initialized to the current locale).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one;

First we get the device language, then we set the locale of `NSDateFormatter`
 with that language.

```
NSString * deviceLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale * locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:deviceLanguage];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Comment: Will this localize the "dd MMMM" part?  I think it won't.
Some locales should have "dd MMMM" while others should have "MMMM dd"

Comment: @delta2flat In that case you should use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties of the formatter instead of `dateFormat`. It will handle the order of the units based on locale.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing it wrong. What you should do is change the `Region Format`, not the `Language` of the device.

Go to `Settings->General->International->Region Format` to change it and test it again.

I hope it helps.

EDIT: Using the `Language` is not a good idea. iOS is not translated to that many languages. However it supports a lot of region formats.

Example: I live in Bulgaria. iOS is not translated to bulgarian, so the actual menus and apps use English language, but as I have set my `Region Format` to Bulgaria, all of the date formats, date labels and currency labels are the bulgarian ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use Desdenova's answer to have working code.

To test it (and take screenshots, for example), you'll need to change the device's language AND the region format.

If you only change the device's language, it may change the date a little bit, but the months and days (the names) will still be in the language of the region format.